Literal meaning of ただでは when used as a threat

「マルフォイ、これ以上一言でも言ってみろ。ただでは....」 (Harry Potter (book 1), Japanese translation)
Malfoy, you'd better not say another word, or else... (my TL)

(The ellipsis in the Japanese sentence is as written, I have not omitted anything.)
I'm trying to understand the meaning and the logic behind ただでは....
Looking in Jisho I see ただでは translated as "This isn't over; I will get my revenge" and a full sentence, ただではおかないぞ, translated as "You'll pay for this!; You'd better keep your mouth shut!"
Looking on alc.co.jp I see things like:

ただでは済まされない have its consequences; be going to pay
～というのはただでは済まない  never get away with

The general gist seems to be that I can translate ただでは as 'or else...', i.e. it is a threat of some retribution if the listener doesn't do what they're told,  but I don't understand where it comes from. To me ただで means 'for free'. The completions above (おかない, 済まない etc.) aren't serving to enlighten me. What are the literal translations of these expressions and how do they come to have their meanings in this context?

According to デジタル大辞泉, ただ can mean:

ただ【▽徒／×只】
1⃣［名］
２ 何事もなく、そのままであること。無事。「見つかったらただでは済まない」

and according to 学研全訳古語辞典, ただ(なり) had this meaning in Classical Japanese:

ただ・なり 【直なり・徒なり】
形容動詞ナリ活用
④ 何もせずにそのままである。何事もない。
出典源氏物語　藤裏葉
「ただに見過ぐさむこと惜しき盛りなるに」
[訳] 何もせずにそのまま見過ごしてしまうには惜しい花盛りなので。

So ただ has (or had) a meaning 「何事もなく/何もせずそのままである(こと)、何事もない（こと）、無事」.
「ただでは済まない」 literally means 「無事・何事もなく/何もしないでそのまま("safely, without doing anything/without anything happening, leaving as it is")」+「では済まない・では終わらない」("things won't be settled, it won't end")
